# How to use pdflib get text sentence by sentence?

Tags: pdflib

[pdflib](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-gmbh/)  is a  good software to analysis PDF. When I use it to extract text from a PDF. How to extract text sentence by sentence? Now I can only extract by word, line, page. For example, give the following content in PDF:

```
I want to extract text from pdf
Sentence by sentence. Is there 
anybody can help?
```

the word mode return one word each time (i.e. I; want; to; extract...), the line mode return one line each time(i.e. I want to extract text from pdf; Sentence by sentence Is there; anyboy can help?). The page mode return the whole paragraph. What I want to get is sentence each time (i.e. I want to extract text from PDF sentence by sentence； Is there anybody can help?)

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the support, and the below is their reply:

Hello,

this is not possible by TET. I assume you refer to TET (not PDFlib), which
is our Text extraction toolkit.

To retrieve the content by sentence, you must add a post process which
determine the sentence end and then return the string as you want.
For example, when you use granularity word, you loop over all words.
Then you combine all words, until the word is s sentence break. Then 
you return the string. 
However, this must be done in *your* code.